# Is there a WIKI (preferably .NET) that uses Markdown as it's editor?

Tags: asp.net, wiki, markdown, wiki-engine

I am looking to set up an internal wiki for our development/design team.

**The key feature I am looking for is a very simple editor with revision history**.  Ideally, the uber-simple markup system StackOverflow.com uses ([Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)) would be great.  One of the reasons for this is that we have non-technical people (managers, sales people, designers) who would benefit from a clean markup, not having to know HTML, and yet still be able to view revisions and make modifications easily.

I have tried ScrewTurn Wiki, but it seems its markup is very ugly, and thier latest WYSIWYG seems kinda buggy (keeps adding lines on revisions).

I would be willing to use a non-.NET solution if it provided a turn key solution.  I would just prefer .NET since we are a .NET house.

Comment: StackOverflow's uses the Markdown markup system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Comment: unfortunately I can't finy any wiki's that use markdown.  There are some that come close, but not exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hamish Graham has created an [ASP.NET Wiki Control with Markdown](http://wikicontrol.codeplex.com/) that you can download from Codeplex. You may be able to roll you own Wiki using this control just as [Hamish Graham apparently has done on his blog](http://www.hamishgraham.net/page/Downloads.aspx/ASP.NET-Wiki-Control-with-Markdown).

Answer (score 3):

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), the engine behind Wikipedia.  It's PHP-based, but has the significant advantage of being familiar to a great many people.

Comment: Mediawiki is the enigine behind Wikipedia.

Comment: MediaWiki is good, certainly, and I'm a long-time user. But... what exactly is StackOverflow-like in its editor?

Answer (score 3):

[MindTouch](http://www.mindtouch.com) is OpenSource and .Net based.  Ohloh has rated it as a 5.  The source code is pretty tight, and there are connectors for SqlServer as well as a scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

docuwiki for PHP is quite simple and has a similar-style editor. i am not sure about the .net alternative though.

Comment: screwturn uses almost identical markup and is written in .net

Answer (score 1):

Have you really had that big of an issue with [ScrewTurn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/)?

It seems very nice, compact and pretty simple.

There is another list of open source ASP.NET wiki engines [here.](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/wiki-engines)

Comment: The latest version's editor was an abomination.  Next to impossible to keep the markup cleanly formatted.

Comment: Version 3.0.2 fixes a number of the Visual editor issues, but its still not perfect.

Comment: @jrummell: thanks, I am going to update to the latest version and hopefully screwturn becomes the wiki I was hoping for.

Comment: We actually just switched from ScrewTurn to Confluence. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

We just switched from ScrewTurn to [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/starter/). We just couldn't get non-technical people to adopt a wiki without Word-like editing. ScrewTurn's Visual editor is getting better, but we had set the Wiki Markup editor as the default to avoid issues.

Confluence isn't free, but it is rather cheap for a limited number of users. You can get the starter license for $10, which gives you their full featured wiki for 10 users (Same with JIRA too! Great for small teams).

Comment: Worth pointing out that Confluence gets a *lot* more expensive for more than 10 users.